# Pycharm local variable is not used

Tags: python, pycharm

I am writing a program for college that takes a command and modifies a list. When i try to assign to my list the return value of function , it tells me the variable isn't used , even though i am using it in the function too.
the function call:

```
data = filter_category(function["expense"], data)
```

the function:

```
def filter_category(expense, data):
    for e in data:
        if e[2] != expense:
            data.remove(e)
    return data
```

[SS of Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP1bh.png)
Did i write something wrong or is this a bug from Pycharm?

Comment: you are iterating data and inside the iteration you are removing elements from data. don't do that, it will cause problems. instead create a new list. Your function could just be one line:   `return [e for e in data if e[2] == expense]`. Your question though is about something different. The `data` variable you use to call the function is not the same as the data parameter you use inside the function. So Pycharm is telling you that the value that your function returns is assigned to `data` but not used anywhere.

Comment: It would be better if you shared more of the code, we don't know what is happening in your program that makes PyCharm say that. Furthermore, as @SembeiNorimaki mentioned, don't change your iterable while iterating over it with a for-loop, its bad practice and can cause issues.

Comment: What is `data`? You pass it into your function without telling us what it is. Nor do you show what you use it for afterwards.

Comment: @quamrana "I am writing a program for college that takes a command and modifies a **list**"

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki so the OP says, but there is no proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE only evaluates the assignment here. Yes, you are using "data" to give it to your method, but assigning the return value of the method to data something like a new variable for everything after this method call. As you don't use this newly assigned value it deems this assignment as useless and tells you, that it is not used.

If you would do something with data after the method call, this warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify a list while iterating it as it is generally not safe.

```
def filter_category(expense, data):
    filtered_data = []
    
    for e in data:
        if e[2] == expense:
            filtered_data.append(e)

    return filtered_data
```

As to your issue, `data` gets passed by reference and is used in the function to create another list. The warning will go away if you use your newly assigned `data` after calling the function. You used the function to filter the list, but surely you need to use that filtered data now?